# How to use map base field definition in a custom content entity form

Tags: 8, entities

I have a custom content entity and i'd like to use a `map` BaseFieldDefinition type to hold an arbitrary number of options.

This is in my custom content entity `baseFieldsDefinitions()`:

```
$fields['options'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
      ->setLabel(t('Task options'))
      ->setDescription(t('The task options.'))
      ->setSettings(array(
           'type' => 'map',
            'default_value' => null
       ));
```

How do I display this as part of the entity form?

My instinct is that I'd need to create a custom widget, custom formatter and add the following to the base field definition:

```
->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
         'type' => 'custom_widget',
          'weight' => -6,
  ))
```

Any direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your instinct is right, what's stopping you from doing exactly that? Map doesn't have default widget/formatter as it's basicaly just a generic key/value storage. That said, your definition is fairly wrong, the argument to create() is the type, there is no type setting and default_value has not been a setting for years, there are separate methods to set the default.

Comment: thanks, so I would use `BaseFieldDefinition::create('map')`, remove the `->setSettings(...)`, write my custom widget and then declare it in the `setDisplayOptions('form',  ...)` as above?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: @RobotEyes Hei, Hope you could assist me. I also have a field with type map, but I can't display it when creating a view, so I think I might have to create a custom widget as you mentioned, how would I go about creating a custom widget for this one specific field?